# Como hago un redirect link tengo esto:

Tags: dns, seo

Alguien sabe como hacer un redirect link [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.